# web dev - server not pointing to laravel 7.3 public, displaying 'Index of /' page

Tags: php, vuejs2, single-page-application, laravel-7, inertiajs

I have created a new laravel project in a fresh public_html dir on my work's server using

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel public_html
```

I have created the .vue component and the controller to display the homepage upon visiting the site but instead all that is displayed is this:
[image: faulty display]

here is the web.php file for the handling the request:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', [HomepageContoller::class, 'index'])
   ->name('home');
```

here is the HomepageController class:

```
<?php

namespace App\HTTP\Controllers;

use Inertia\Inertia;

class HomepageContoller extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        return Inertia::render('Homepage/Index');
    }
}

?>
```

and here is the .vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Brite Visual Products<h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  metaInfo: { title: 'Brite Visual Products' },
}
</script>
```

everything is exactly where it belongs, nothing has been moved since the `composer create-project` call

UPDATE:

it seems as though the issue is just that the web root is being pointed at public_html/ and not public_html/public/

to fix that i will need to have higher permissions on my work's server, will post a full solution later

Comment: Your web server is not configured correctly.

Comment: yes, it has become clear the issue lies in where the web root is pointing, however in my etc file there is no apache2 dir to edit the root configuration usually found in sites-available or conf dirs

Comment: If you go to the public directory and click on the index.php what happens? Does it download that file?

Comment: @Kerkouch do you mean in the index of / page being displayed? if so, no it returns a 500 error if i try and look at any .php files, no problem with .json and other similar types

Comment: @Kerkouch just confirmed that i cannot see the apache web root files because i dont have correct permissions, i believe that is where the problem lies. How will i have to configure the `/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` once i can edit it to point towards `public/` inside of `public_html`/?

Comment: 500 error means PHP is installed and working. You need to configure the VirtualHost under `/etc/apache/sites-available/` and set the `DocumentRoot` to point to the `public/` directory, then enable the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit the following file

```
vi /var/cpanel/userdata/username/domain.com
```

Replace the "username" with your cPanel account username and "domain.com" with your primary domain name and "subdir" with your new directory.

Find the following two lines in this file.

```
documentroot: /home/username/public_html
path: /home/username/public_html/cgi-bin
```

Modify these two lines to change the document root of your primary domain to a sub-directory inside "public_html" directory.

```
documentroot: /home/username/public_html/subdir
path: /home/username/public_html/subdir/cgi-bin
```

If the primary domain has an SSL certificate installed, edit the following file the same way as above.

```
vim /var/cpanel/userdata/username/domain.com_SSL
```

Save the file after changes are made and then delete the cache file for your primary domain.

```
rm -vf /var/cpanel/userdata/username/domain.com_SSL.cache
```

Run the following scripts to update the user data cache and rebuild apache configuration file.

```
/scripts/updateuserdatacache
/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf
```

Restart Apache server to load changes.

```
service httpd restart
```